# How to use a User Defined Function to iterate through column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone, sql-function

I have a function which converts UTC time into local time based on a certain office location.
The two parameters for the function are the UTC as datetime2 data type and Office as int data type.

```
SELECT [fn].[ConvertFromUTC]('2021-03-14 07:00:00', 5740)
```

Result: `2021-03-14 03:00:00`

Here is the a table that I am wanting to convert all the UTC times to their local times based on the Support Site location (office).[image]

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I tried using something like this but am not sure how to iterate through each support site and UTC time. Suggestions? Would a Cursor be ideal in this scenario?

```
DECLARE @meh nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @x datetime2
DECLARE @y int

Set @x = '2021-03-14 07:00:00'
Set @y = 20608
        
EXEC    @meh = fn.ConvertFromUTC
            @DateTime = @x, 
            @Office = @y

SELECT  @meh
```

Here is the code for the function.

```
ALTER Function [fn].[ConvertFromUTC]
/*This function converts a DateTime from UTC to local time at each office.*/
    
(
@DateTime DATETIME2(0),
@Office int
)

RETURNS DATETIME2(0)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @TimeZone nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @Result DATETIME2(0)
    
    IF @Office IN ('20608','5740')
        BEGIN
            SET @TimeZone = 'US Eastern Standard Time'
            SET @Result = @DateTime at time zone 'UTC' at time zone @TimeZone
        END 
    ELSE IF @Office = '597'
        BEGIN
            SET @TimeZone = 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            SET @Result = @DateTime at time zone 'UTC' at time zone @TimeZone
            SET @Result = DATEADD(HOUR,-1,@Result) /* 'AT TIME ZONE' functionality for Europe uses the wrong offset. This corrects it.*/
        END 
    ELSE IF @Office = '6179' /*Not using 'AT TIME ZONE' functionality because it doesn't recognize that Australia observes Daylight Savings Time*/
        BEGIN   
            /*DateTime is the end and beginning of Sydney daylight savings time in UTC. 
            Ends first Sunday in April at 2:00:00 and begins first Sunday in October at 3:00:00
            In UTC, Ends first Saturday in April at 16:00:00 and begins first Saturday in October 16:00:00*/
            IF @DateTime >= DATEADD(dd, (5-(DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(mm,(YEAR(@DateTime)-1900) * 12 + 3,0))%7)),DATEADD(mm,(YEAR(@DateTime)-1900) * 12 + 3,0))+'16:00:00'
            AND @DateTime < DATEADD(dd,0 + (5-(DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(mm,(YEAR(@DateTime)-1900) * 12 + 9,0))%7)),DATEADD(mm,(YEAR(@DateTime)-1900) * 12 + 9,0))+'16:00:00'
                BEGIN
                    SET @Result = DATEADD(hour,10,@DateTime)    
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @Result = DATEADD(hour,11,@DateTime)    
                END
        END 

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Comment: If you want to iterate you are going wrong. SQL is a set based language; the last thing you should be doing is iterating. What are you *really* trying to achieve here? Also the above doesn't make sense, you don't `EXECUTE` a function.

Comment: Don't you just want something like `UPDATE MyTable SET DateColumn = [fn].[ConvertFromUTC](UtcDateColumn, 5740)`? Iterating is almost always a bad idea in SQL

Comment: The optimal way would be to use a *table-valued function* as using an inline *scalar function* can be as bad as iterating. Using a TVF you would simply `update` your table and `apply` the function.

Comment: I agree that iterating through the table would be a bad idea. A member on our team had created this function, and I was asked to test it and see if it would be better used instead of a bunch of CASE statements which is what is currently used.

Comment: @Stu, would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using, there is now good support for handling trimezones it may be the function is not even necessary - without seeing a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) though it's not possible to know.

Comment: [Example of table valued functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-inline-table-valued-function/)

Comment: @Stu, I'm using version 13. Ultimately this table's data is used in a Qlik report which is updated everyday

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT [fn].[ConvertFromUTC](t.YourDate, 5740) FROM YourTable t`? Although as mentioned a TVF is faster, but we can't convert it unless you give us the code

Comment: @Charlieface, I updated the post by including the function's code.

Comment: `'AT TIME ZONE' functionality for Europe uses the wrong offset` is an interesting statement, are you sure you have the right time zone, perhaps you want `GMT Standard Time`?

Comment: And Australia it depends on state, you prob want `AUS Eastern Standard Time`. So you could actually use `AT TIME ZONE` for all of this

Comment: @Charlieface awesome! I will check this out. I didn't write the function, but will see what changes I can make to simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly, what you have currently is termed a *scalar User Defined Function (UDF)*.**

You can use it quite simply like this:

```sql
SELECT fn.ConvertFromUTC(t.YourDate, 5740)
FROM YourTable t;
```

---

**Scalar UDFs are slow for various reasons and should be avoided**, and although most are helped by SQL Server 2019's UDF inlining, **it is normally better to rewrite this as an *inline Table Valued Function***. This returns a rowset, and is a bit like a parameterized view.

To make it inline, it *must* be a **single** `RETURN (SELECT` statement

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER Function [fn].[ConvertFromUTC]
/*This function converts a DateTime from UTC to local time at each office.*/
(
  @DateTime DATETIME2(0),
  @Office int
)

RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT Result = CASE 
      WHEN @Office IN ('20608', '5740')
        THEN @DateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'
      WHEN @Office = '597'
        THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, @DateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time')
      WHEN @Office = '6179'
        THEN 

            /*DateTime is the end and beginning of Sydney daylight savings time in UTC. 
            Ends first Sunday in April at 2:00:00 and begins first Sunday in October at 3:00:00
            In UTC, Ends first Saturday in April at 16:00:00 and begins first Saturday in October 16:00:00*/

            CASE WHEN @DateTime >= DATEADD(dd, (5-(DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(mm, (YEAR(@DateTime) - 1900) * 12 + 3, 0)) %7)), DATEADD(mm,(YEAR(@DateTime) - 1900) * 12 + 3, 0)) + '16:00:00'
                AND @DateTime < DATEADD(dd, 0 + (5 - (DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(mm, (YEAR(@DateTime)-1900) * 12 + 9, 0)) % 7)), DATEADD(mm,(YEAR(@DateTime) - 1900) * 12 + 9, 0)) + '16:00:00'
                THEN DATEADD(hour,10,@DateTime)    
                ELSE DATEADD(hour,11,@DateTime)    
            END
      END 
);

GO
```

You can use it like this:

```sql
SELECT utc.Result
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY fn.ConvertFromUTC(t.YourDate, 5740) utc;

-- Because it's only one value you can also do this

SELECT
  (SELECT utc.Result FROM fn.ConvertFromUTC(t.YourDate, 5740))
FROM YourTable t;
```

---

**I must say, I take issue with the original writer of this function, who clearly knows about `AT TIME ZONE`, but thinks it doesn't work properly.**

```
            SET @TimeZone = 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            SET @Result = @DateTime at time zone 'UTC' at time zone @TimeZone
            SET @Result = DATEADD(HOUR,-1,@Result) /* 'AT TIME ZONE' functionality for Europe uses the wrong offset. This corrects it.*/
```

Europe is not monolithic, presumably the correct time zone should have been `'GMT Standard Time'`.

```
    ELSE IF @Office = '6179' /*Not using 'AT TIME ZONE' functionality because it doesn't recognize that Australia observes Daylight Savings Time*/
        BEGIN   
            /*DateTime is the end and beginning of Sydney daylight savings time in UTC.
```

Again, Australia is not one time zone, and I suspect that `E. Australia Standard Time` was used instead of `'AUS Eastern Standard Time'`.

You can see all the available time zones on the server with `select * from sys.time_zone_info`, you can also add more time zones via Windows.

**Another thing is that this function is supposed to `converts a DateTime from UTC to local time`**, but using `AT TIME ZONE` twice is used only when converting from one time zone to another, it should only be done once if the time is already in `'UTC'`.

One further point: **I suggest you actually store the correct time zone within the table you are querying,** then you can pass through the *time zone* instead of `@Office` and avoid a bunch of `CASE` expressions.

Comment: I would recommend using datetimeoffset instead of a separate column that stores the time zone.  This would then store the value in UTC with the correct offset included.